# how to ascertain current value of source in the bind method of a custom binding

Tags: aurelia

Anyone know how one can ascertain the current value of the source in the `bind` method of a custom binding?

The `bind` method is defined as follows:

`bind(binding, scope, [args...])`

When `bind` is invoked, I would like to know the value of the viewmodel property (source) that is implicated in the binding.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your custom binding behaviour class, you can intercept the property's value by overriding the `updateTarget()` and `updateSource()` methods. For instance:

```
const interceptMethods = ['updateTarget', 'updateSource', 'callSource'];

export class InterceptBindingBehavior {
  bind(binding, scope, interceptor) {
    let i = interceptMethods.length;
    while (i--) {
      let method = interceptMethods[i];
      if (!binding[method]) {
        continue;
      }
      binding[`intercepted-${method}`] = binding[method];
      let update = binding[method].bind(binding);
      binding[method] = interceptor.bind(binding, method, update);
    }

    binding.updateTarget = value => {
      //do something with value;
    }

    binding.updateSource = value => {
      //do something with value;
    }
  }

  unbind(binding, scope) {
    let i = interceptMethods.length;
    while (i--) {
      let method = interceptMethods[i];
      if (!binding[method]) {
        continue;
      }
      binding[method] = binding[`intercepted-${method}`];
      binding[`intercepted-${method}`] = null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Fabio, thanks for your suggestion.  However, `updateTarget` doesn't work to obtain the _initial_ value of the source at the time bind() is invoked.  It is only called when the value _changes_.